# wx.App runs in one program and not in another

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to get the screen size for a project I am working on to create a window. I am using wxPython. Here is the code

```
import wx
app = wx.App(False)
width, height = wx.GetDisplaySize()
del(app)
print(width, type(width))
print(height, type(height))
```

When I run the code in a scrap program I use for testing it works fine but when I add it to my main program it seems to get stuck indenwitently on the line `app = wx.app(False)` and I am not sure why. Not sure what other code to post but if anyone can help that would be grand.

Comment: It's difficult to tell without seeing the code that is actually failing.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony thats exactly my issue. That is the code. I copy it from one program to other. Works in first fails in second. Event when I only call that function and not the rest of the program. The only thing that changed is that the main program takes in arguments using argparse

Comment: Context! You aren't showing us the context. Instead, you have isolated that piece of code.